# c++: How to quit a multi-threading program properly

Tags: multithreading, c++11, thread-safety, signals

In my c++11 project, I need to generate two threads which run infinitely. Here is an example:

```
static vector<int> vec;
static std::mutex mtx;
static std::condition_variable cond;
static bool done = false;
void f1()
{
    while(!done)
    {
        // do something with vec and mtx
    }
}

void f2()
{
    while(!done)
    {
        // do something with vec and mtx
    }
}

thread t1(f1);
thread t2(f2);

void finish(int s)
{
    done = true;
    // what should I do???
}

int main()
{    
    signal(SIGINT, finish);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Normally, I won't stop or kill this program. But in case of exception, I think I need to do something for `ctrl-c`, which is used to kill the program. But I don't know how to quit this program properly.

If I'm right, `t1` and `t2` might continue executing even if the `main` has returned 0. So I think I need to make them detach like this:

```
void finish()
{
    done = true;
    t1.detach();
    t2.detach();
}
```

However, when I execute the program and do `ctrl-c`, I get an error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'

I've found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684218/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-stdsystem-error-threadpool), so I think the problem is the same: `mtx` and/or `cond` has been destroyed while `t1` or `t2` hasn't finished yet.

So how could I kill the program properly? Or I don't need to deal with the signal `ctrl-c` and the program itself knows what to do to quit properly?

Comment: No that looks almost right. Except that `done` should probably be a [`std::atomic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) instead of a plain `bool`. If you detach the threads they can't be joined.

Comment: And to alleviate your worries: For an undetached thread, the `join` function will not return until the thread has truly ended. That means your `main` function will not end (and the process exit) unless both threads have exited.

Comment: general rule for this kind of problems is to use thread sanitizer. Did you do that?

Comment: also if you use IDE like visual studio you may be able to debug it and get more info

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude .   So I don't need to make them detach in the function `finish`?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl .   Nop, first time to hear thread sanitizer . :D

Comment: No, not if you want to join them, and wait for their exit.

Comment: @Yves but you have 1740 points, it is a requirement :P Anyway you will need either gcc or clang since VS does not support it.  https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerCppManual

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl . wow . that's wonderful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude . I just tested again. I think I can't use detach because I always get the same error. I think the reason is just as the link said: the mutex is free because the main has finished while the thread hasn't finished. So I have to wait for their exit.

Comment: If you call `join` on a detached thread an exception will be thrown. For starters. And as I told you multiple times, if you call `join` before the `main` function ends you will not have a problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude .  It woks!    Could you make an answer? I would like to accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`done` should be `std::atomic<bool>`, or unsequenced reads/writes are not legal.

Accessing atomic variables is only safe in a signal handler if `std::atomic<bool>::is_lock_free` is true.  Check that.  If it isn't true, your program should probably abort with an error in `main`.

When you `.join()`, you wait for the thread to finish executing.  And you don't want to exit `main` unless the threads have finished.

In short, do this:

```
static std::atomic<bool> done = false;
```

(rest of code goes here)

```
int main()
{    
  if (!done.is_lock_free()) return 10; // error
  signal(SIGINT, finish);
  t1.join();
  t2.join();
}
```